# Angular Directive Does Not Evaluate Inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following setup:

App/Directive

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.directive("adminRosterItem", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            displayText: "@"
        },
        template: "<td>{{ displayText }}</td>", // should I have this?
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            // What do I put here? I don't seem to have any
            // element to initialize (set up event handlers, for example)
        },
        compile: function(?,?,?){} // should I have this? If so, what goes inside?
    }
});
```

Controller

```
function PositionsController($scope) {
           $scope.positions = [{ Name: "Quarterback", Code: "QB" },
                               { Name: "Wide Receiver", Code: "WR" }
                              ]; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="PositionsController">            
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="position in positions">
                <admin-roster-item displayText="{{ position.Name + ' (' + position.Code + ')' }}"></admin-roster-item>
             </tr>
         </table>       
    </div>
</div>
```

It's a very simple example, but I can't get it to render. Perhaps there's something that tutorials aren't telling me, or that is secret Angular knowledge?

If I remove the directive inside the `<tr ng-repeat="..." />` and place `<td>{{ displayText }}</td>` instead, it will show all records.

But I want the directive to be more complicated than just a single `<td>{{}}</td>` (eventually) so that I could reuse this directive in multiple apps.

So, I'm really asking how do we properly create a directive that goes inside ng-repeat? What am I missing? What should be taken off from the code above?

Comment: There is an issue in AngularJS's tracker about this: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1459

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Agree that you need to think about where the directive begins and ends.  Here's a plnkr that illustrates a directive bound to each item in the array - http://plnkr.co/edit/IU8fANreYP7NYrs4swTW?p=preview

If you want the directive to encapsulate the enumerating of a collection defined by a parent scope it gets a bit tricker.  I'm not sure if the following is 'best practice', but it's how i've handled it -- http://plnkr.co/edit/IU8fANreYP7NYrs4swTW?p=preview

When relying on the directive to perform the iteration you get involved with transclusion, which is a made up word that means (as i understand it) take the content defined in the parent, push it into the directive and then evaluate it.  I've been working with angular for a few months, and I'm starting to think that asking the directive to iterate is a smell, and I've always been able to design around it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "think about where the directive begins and ends." I did look at the plnkr code and got the pattern. The use of the isolate "=" seems to work for this one. I also removed the table, tr, and td and used divs instead. It didn't work with the table structure but it did with the divs.

Comment: I mean that it's important to think about the directive in terms of what value is it providing to the the view that is using it.  I find that directives are easiest to manage if they are small, tightly encapsulated chunks of ui + behavior.  If I lose site of the core functionality that the directive is meant to provide (and start it starts taking on too many responsibilities) the complexity starts to overwhelm.

Comment: "Transclusion" is not a made up word: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transclusion :)

Answer (score 9):

Ignoring all the theoretical aspects, you can get your code to work by making two simple changes.

1. don't use mixed case in your attribute names.  `displaytext` *not* `displayText`
2. put the `<td>` tags outside the directive, in the template

Do that and it will work; it think those are both Angular bugs.

Comment: Shocking! It works even when I didn't apply the other advices above (though, they're still good to know). The table handling seems to be "uncooperative", though - tried making the template root a tr and put ng-repeat on the table - didn't work. Switched everything to div and span, and it works, though layout looks messed up.

Comment: Sugestion 2 solves it. Sugestion 1 is unnecessary (use camelCase on javascript, hyphened-tags on HTML).

Answer (score 2):

i think the right way to approach this would be to send the object into admin roster item, like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="position in positions">
  <admin-roster-item pos="position">         
  </admin-roster-item>
</tr>
```

and in the directive:

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.directive("adminRosterItem", function () {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
        pos: "@"
    },
    template: "<td>{{ formattedText }}</td>", // should I have this?
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        // all of this can easily be done with a filter, but i understand you just want to     
        // know how it works
        scope.formattedText = scope.pos.Name + ' (' + scope.pos.Code + ')';
    }
  }
});
```

PS. i didn't test this!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing your directive as a child of ng-repeat, try keeping the custom directive on the same level as ng-repeat, this

```
<tr ng-repeat="position in positions" admin-roster-item displayText="{{ position.Name + ' (' + position.Code + ')' }}"></tr>
```

And furthermore, allow your custom directive to be used as an attribute. AngulaJS has defined ng-repeats priority as 1000, so at times when you custom directive is made, it does not go down well with ng-repeat.

A second option (try only if the first one fails) is to set the priority of your custom directive more than that of ngRepeat i.e. to 1001.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue, where the ng-repeat in my view wass not evaluated if the view contained directive ('mydirective')

My directive definition was

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'components/directives/mydirective.html',
      restrict: 'EA',
      controller: 'MyDirectiveController',
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      }
    };
  });
```

and my view controller definition was

```
  angular.module('myApp')
    .component('myView', {
      templateUrl: 'app/views/myview.html',
      controller: myViewComponent,
      controllerAs: "vm"
    });
```

you can notice both controllers are refered by 'vm' by using 'controllerAs' parameter. This is the reason for the problem. When the directive is present in the view, angular always refers the 'vm' defined in directive controller rather than view's.

When I give different names for controller references, problem disappeared

Now, My directive definition is

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'components/directives/mydirective.html',
      restrict: 'EA',
      controller: 'MyDirectiveController',
      controllerAs: 'directiveVM',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      }
    };
  });
```

and my view controller definition was

```
  angular.module('myApp')
    .component('myView', {
      templateUrl: 'app/views/myview.html',
      controller: myViewComponent,
      controllerAs: "viewCtrlVM"
    });
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Had exact same problem.
Had a custom directive in an ng-repeat, table->tr->td->directive, and when sorting the table using ng-repeat and Array.sort the table did change order but the directives did not re-render. The problem  was I was using

```
track by $index
```

removed the track by index from the ng-repeat and it was fixed.