# ng-repeat with tables in Angular JS and directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to build a [responsive data table](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/responsive_design_approach_for_complex_multicolumn_data_tables/) using Angular with a directive and ng-repeat. I have managed to get the ng-repeat to work with tables: http://jsfiddle.net/raff77/Asb8k/

```
{}
```

I am now trying to get it to work with a directive and the ng-repeat does not work. http://jsfiddle.net/raff77/uwGXb/3/

```
{}
```

Is there a way to get the ng-repeat to work with your directive or should you build that into your directive. Notice I have built out a solution to add the rows as strings then html but i want to avoid this and do things the Angular way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in AngularJS when you want to put 'td's into a table in a directive. See this question [Angular Directive Does Not Evaluate Inside ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754889/angular-directive-does-not-evaluate-inside-ng-repeat) and particularly this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15755234/669561.
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1459

And I don't really see, why you want to fill up the table with a directive. Your first approach without the table seems to work perfectly fine and I cannot see any advanteges over using directives.

Comment: Hi DanEEStar, i want to build a directive that takes the definition of a table head and some parameters, like sort, search, pagination and automatically build a widget. This was just the first step.

I read those posts and believe I need to build a compile function into my directive and build out the ng-repeat in there. I will also have to add filters etc. Thanks for your time.

Comment: The grid seems to perform poorly but thanks, will look into the code and look at building or extending.

Comment: As a matter of interest, where should you manipulate the template when writing directives. I want to define the head of my table for a grid and have the directive build out a template before linking.

Comment: Found that, I should manipulate the DOM template in the compile function but in the link functions.

Answer (score 3):

You are creating a new scope in the directive as shown here

`scope: {
          gbsdata: '='
        },`

But "chartdata" is the array you were watching, which is not available in this scope.

```
scope.$watch("chartdata", function (chartdata) {
```

Check this fiddle it will help you. http://jsfiddle.net/KLGrV/1/

Comment: Ahh yes thats a typo but that was me trying to convert the code I had written for locally