# How can I place directives in a table?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a directive inside a table, with angularjs. I can generally get it working, except if I try to put custom elements (in my jsfiddle, `<person />`) inside a table, the browser generally tends to pull it out of the table, and prepend the element.

http://jsfiddle.net/drewsonne/WSnyZ/16/

I'm expecting:

```html
<div ng-app="MyApp" class="ng-scope">
    <people class="ng-scope">
        <table>
            <thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Age</th></tr></thead>
            <tbody>
                <person info="personJohn" class="ng-isolate-scope ng-scope ng-binding">
                    <tr><td>John</td><td>10</td></tr>
                </person>
                <person info="personSally" class="ng-isolate-scope ng-scope ng-binding">
                    <tr><td>Sally</td><td>20</td></tr>
                </person>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </people>
    <person info="{name:'Fred',age:30}" class="ng-isolate-scope ng-scope ng-binding">
        <tr><td>Fred</td><td>30</td></tr>
   </person>
</div>
```

but I'm getting:

```html
<div ng-app="MyApp" class="ng-scope">
    <people class="ng-scope">
        <person info="personJohn" class="ng-isolate-scope ng-scope ng-binding">
            John10
        </person>
        <person info="personSally" class="ng-isolate-scope ng-scope ng-binding">
            Sally20
        </person>
        <table>
            <thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Age</th></tr></thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    </people>
    <person info="{name:'Fred',age:30}" class="ng-isolate-scope ng-scope ng-binding">
        Fred30
    </person>
</div>
```

**QUESTION:**

**Is it possible to place custom elements inside a table, or this something the browser will just steam roll?**

---

**Notes:**

My over arching motivation is so that I could have something like:

```html
<year info="data"></year>
```

which templates to something like this:

```html
<year>
    <table ng-repeat="year in data">
        <thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Value</th></tr></thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr><th colspan=2>{{year.name}}</th></tr>
        <quarter ng-repeat="quarter in year.quarters">
            <tr><th>{{quarter.name}}</th></tr>
            <month>
                <tr><th>{{month.name}}</th></tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="day in month.days">
                    <th>{{day.name}}</th>
                    <th>{{day.value}}</th>
                </tr>
            </month>
        </quarter>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</year>
```

which renders something like this:

```html
<table>
        <thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Value</th></tr></thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr><th colspan=2>2013</th></tr>
            <tr><th>Quarter 1</th></tr>
            <tr><th>February</th></tr>
            <tr>
                <td>01/02/2013</td>
                <td>$12</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>05/02/2013</td>
                <td>$15</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>10/02/2013</td>
                <td>$17</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
<table>
        <thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Value</th></tr></thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr><th colspan=2>2013</th></tr>
            <tr><th>Quarter 2</th></tr>
            <tr><th>April</th></tr>
            <tr>
                <td>01/04/2013</td>
                <td>$18</td>
            </tr>
            <tr><th>May</th></tr>
            <tr>
                <td>01/05/2013</td>
                <td>$78</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16789745/2057033 :) .

Comment: Hmmm... sooo, that means I can't do it. Dammit. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are careful to use valid table elements and rely on something like attribute directives it seems to work just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Tz83w/1/

```
'<tr ng-repeat="d in data" info="d"></tr>'
...
.directive('info', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
...
template: '<tr><td>{{info.name}}</td><td>{{info.Age}}</td></tr>'
```